# Python: How to print only values that appears at least n times

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, iteration

I am currently working with .csv file in my python code. there are over than 1 million data and I want to print only the value (time stamp) that appears at least 10 times in the data. This is my current code:

```
import csv
with open('cut2.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
 data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
 time_stamp = 't'

 for row, time_stamp in data:
    if time_stamp >= 10:
        print('object found at {}'.format(time_stamp))
```

the format of data in my .csv file is x,y,p,t this is a short snap of my csv file

```
x,y,p,t
1050,397,1,31531
1074,397,1,31531
1025,398,1,31531
1026,398,1,31531
1048,398,1,31531
1052,398,1,31531
1067,398,1,31531
1084,398,1,31531
1011,399,1,31532
1018,407,1,31532
1024,407,1,31532
1033,407,1,31532
1042,407,1,31532
1054,407,1,31532
1058,407,1,31532
1061,407,1,31532
1077,407,1,31532
1030,406,1,31532
1033,406,1,31532
1044,406,1,31532
1056,406,1,31532
1058,406,1,31532
1063,406,1,31532
1087,406,1,31532
1094,406,1,31532
1036,405,1,31532
1050,405,1,31532
1069,405,1,31532
1079,405,1,31532
1098,405,1,31532
```

I get this error message

```
    for row, time_stamp in data:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

does anyone knows how to fix this ? any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: You have to brush up dictionary concepts.
Here you have to write data.items() in for loop

Comment: @poohbear119 Please provide more code. It's impossible to debug your problem with the amount of info you provided.

Comment: @matszwecja I have updated the code, let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: short example of the structure of your csv file would also be helpful.

Comment: @HiralTalsaniya no, because `data` is not a dictionary

Comment: Okay, one more thing, what would be expected output for the example data? `if time_stamp >= 10:` - this is not a clear requirement

Comment: @matszwecja the expected output would be 'object found at 31532'. what would be a clear requirement? Thanks

Comment: 31531 would not get printed because there is only 8 lines with this timestamp, 31532 would because there is more than 10 lines matching - Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @matszwecja yup, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of rewriting needed to make your code work like you want it to. Most importantly, Python will not magically group your data based on some condition - you need to tell it how it is supposed to do this. Easiest way would be using `collections.Counter`, which you increment for each row with a given timestamp.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
with open('cut2.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    counter = Counter()
    for row_dict in data:
        counter[row_dict['t']] += 1
    for time_stamp, occurences in counter.items():
        if occurences >= 10:
            print('object found at {}'.format(time_stamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` to make matching and filtering easier:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('cut2.csv')

repeated_timestamps = df.groupby('t').size() >= 10
timestamps_of_interest = [row[0] for row in repeated_timestamps.items() if row[1]]  # row[0] is the timestamp, row[1] is True or False depending on the count

for ts in timestamps_of_interest:
    print(f'Timestamp: {ts}')
    for row in df[df['t'] == ts].iterrows():  # Note the parenthesis!
        print(f'x: {row[1]["x"]}, y: {row[1]["y"]}, p: {row[1]["p"]}')
```

Output (with your example slightly modified to have some p's as 1 and others as 0):

```
Timestamp: 31532
x: 1011, y: 399, p: 1
x: 1018, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1024, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1033, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1042, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1054, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1058, y: 407, p: 0
x: 1061, y: 407, p: 0
x: 1077, y: 407, p: 0
x: 1030, y: 406, p: 0
x: 1033, y: 406, p: 0
x: 1044, y: 406, p: 0
x: 1056, y: 406, p: 0
x: 1058, y: 406, p: 0
x: 1063, y: 406, p: 0
x: 1087, y: 406, p: 0
x: 1094, y: 406, p: 0
x: 1036, y: 405, p: 0
x: 1050, y: 405, p: 0
x: 1069, y: 405, p: 0
x: 1079, y: 405, p: 0
x: 1098, y: 405, p: 0
```

You can off course change the format you use to print (or what you'll do with the data later).

In case you want to add additional filters (after the number of timestamps was counted), you can add that to the if:

```py
filtered_df = df[df['p'] == 1]  # Filtering before the loop is more efficient
for ts in timestamps_of_interest:
    print(f'Timestamp: {ts}')
    for row in filtered_df[filtered_df['t'] == ts].iterrows():
        print(f'x: {row[1]["x"]}, y: {row[1]["y"]}, p: {row[1]["p"]}')
```

The result shows only the values with `p == 1`:

```
Timestamp: 31532
x: 1011, y: 399, p: 1
x: 1018, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1024, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1033, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1042, y: 407, p: 1
x: 1054, y: 407, p: 1
```

Comment: Can I also add another conditional statement if I use pandas? for example, if there are several '0' for the p of my .csv data and I only want to print the ones that are '1' for the p

Comment: Sure! But in your case, do you want to count only the value of the timestamps in which `p` is `1` (i.e. select all timestamps that have more than 10 instances with `p == 1`) or select all timestamps that have more than 10 points and only print the points with `p == 1`? The implementation is different for these two cases.

Comment: the latter one is the one that I intend to do. thanks!

Comment: @poohbear119, I extended the answer with an example.